# ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension. (Mac Mountain Lion / Compass / RVM )

Tags: ruby, macos, rubygems

I don't have any clue how to solve this.

I reinstalled the Xcode Commandline tools which were missing previously - but the problem still persists.

Compass and CodeKit do not work as expected.

Any idea what to do?

```
Marcs-Mac-mini:~ marc$ gem update --system
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/openssl/1.0.1f/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/openssl.bundle
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/security.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0/executable-hooks-1.3.1/gem_make.out
 (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
Error loading RubyGems plugin "/Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/gem-wrappers-1.2.4/lib/rubygems_plugin.rb": ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/bin/ruby extconf.rb
/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require': dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/openssl/1.0.1f/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib (LoadError)
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/openssl.bundle
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/openssl.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/security.rb:11:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/package.rb:43:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/installer.rb:9:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1/lib/executable-hooks/regenerate_binstubs_command.rb:2:in `<top (required)>'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
  from extconf.rb:16:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/gems/executable-hooks-1.3.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /Users/marc/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.0@global/extensions/x86_64-darwin-12/2.1.0/executable-hooks-1.3.1/gem_make.out
 (Gem::Ext::BuildError)
ERROR:  Loading command: update (LoadError)
  dlopen(/usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/openssl.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: @@HOMEBREW_CELLAR@@/openssl/1.0.1f/lib/libcrypto.1.0.0.dylib
  Referenced from: /usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.1.0.0.dylib
  Reason: image not found - /usr/local/Cellar/ruby/2.1.0/lib/ruby/2.1.0/x86_64-darwin12.0/openssl.bundle
ERROR:  While executing gem ... (NoMethodError)
    undefined method `invoke_with_build_args' for nil:NilClass
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok … seem to having solved it myself:

```
gem uninstall compass
gem uninstall sass
gem install sass
gem install compass
```

after these step the issue has not been solved …

a rvm reinstall ruby-2.1.0 did the trick…